How to select the best feature?
I have both binary(0=is not or 1=is) and numerical values in x_train data. The target (y_train) is binary (0=is not or 1=is). What is the best method to do feature selection simultaneously?
I used this code:
 from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif x_new = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=8).fit_transform(x_train, y_train)
